# sqlalchemy map entire table into attribute with classical mapping

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

Given the following class and database tables

```py
class Location:
    datacenter_name: str
    path: str

locations = Table(
    "locations",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("path", String, nullable=False),
    Column("datacenter_name", String, nullable=False),
)
mapper_registry.map_imperatively(Location, locations)

backup_registry = Table(
    "backup_registry",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("source_location_id", ForeignKey("locations.id"), nullable=False),
    Column("backup_location_id", ForeignKey("locations.id"), nullable=False),
)
```

I want to map the `backup_registry` table to a BackupRegistry instance, but I need
to map **all rows into a single attribute**, for example:

```py
class BackupRegistry:
    backups: Dict[Location, list[Location]]
```

Using the same approach as with location would give me one BackupRegistry instance
per row `mapper_registry.map_imperatively(BackupRegistry, backup_registry)`

Any thoughts on how this could be accomplished with classical mapping?

Comment: I'm confused about the registry format.  Can you just have something like `location.backup_locations` which is a list of backup locations for the given `location` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the built-in solution to this type of relationship is not working or was just buried in the docs.

```py
class Location:
    pass


locations = Table(
    "locations",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("path", String, nullable=False),
    Column("datacenter_name", String, nullable=False),
)

backup_registry = Table(
    "backup_registry",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("source_location_id", ForeignKey("locations.id"), nullable=False),
    Column("backup_location_id", ForeignKey("locations.id"), nullable=False),
)

mapper_registry.map_imperatively(Location, locations, properties={
    'backup_locations': relationship(Location,
                                     primaryjoin=locations.c.id == backup_registry.c.source_location_id,
                                     secondary=backup_registry,
                                     secondaryjoin=locations.c.id == backup_registry.c.backup_location_id,
                                     backref='source_locations',
    ),
})
```

Then `backup_locations` can be accessed from a `Location` like `location.backup_locations` which will be a `list()` of `Location`s.

This is documented in docs at [self-referential-many-to-many-relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html#self-referential-many-to-many-relationship).

Comment: The idea was to move the responsibility of handling backups into another class different from Location because a kind of "global" knowledge of all available backups is needed. That class should know all the available mappings from Location to backups. Thanks for the answer though, I think I'll end up using sqlalchemy core as I don't see any implementation of what I want with the ORM